# What is the argument of the logarithm operator called?

Tags: logarithms, terminology, exponentiation

> In the expression $\ln(y)$, what is '$y$' called?

I'm asking for a noun analogous to *exponent* in $x^n$, where '$n$' is called the exponent.  If I'm not mistaken, '$x$' in this case is the *radix*, or *base*.  It has the same designation in $\log_x(y)$.

Comment: radix or base for the natural logarithm would be $e$ I imagine there is some Latin word for what you want...

Comment: don't see anything in Abramowitz and Stegun

Comment: I would imagine that considering their inverse relation to one another that y is also known as an exponent at least I've called it that before when trying to show students how to convert a log equation to an exponential equation.

Comment: I suggest calling it the "power".